# Replace NaN inside masked dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
some_dict = {'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': [5,6,7,8],}
df = pd.DataFrame(some_dict)
mask1 = pd.Series([False, True, False, True])
df['c'] = df.loc[mask1, 'a']
```

This will create a new column `c` with NaN-values where `mask1` is `False`, and the values from column `a` where `mask1` is `True`. Now I add `b` to `c`, on a different condition

```
mask2 = pd.Series([True, False, False, False])
df['c'] += df.loc[mask2, 'b']
```

However, this will put ALL values to NaN. I'm guessing this is because `NaN + 0` and `0 + NaN` are both equal to `NaN`. I tried solving this by writing

```
df['c'] = df.loc[mask1, 'a'].fillna(0)
df['c'] = df.loc[mask2, 'b'].fillna(0)
```

Why is replacing `NaN` with `0` through `fillna()` not working?

Comment: I expected to add the values from columns `b` to column `c`, but only where `mask2` is true. And if it's `False`, then just add nothing.

Comment: @armara - `then just add nothing.` - and nothing in `pandas` is `NaN` ;) I think you need add `0` ?

Comment: yeah I didn't mean add `NaN`, i meant add nothing as in `0`

Comment: Try to always match the lvalue's index with the rvalue's one. Otherwise, pandas does its best to reindex the two before doing your operation.  See my answer for a concise and proper way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If check how it working missing values are added only for not matched rows - False valuss in mask:

```
print (df.loc[mask1, 'a'])
1    2
3    4
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

So if want replace NaN there are no missing values, so cannot do it:

```
print (df.loc[mask1, 'a'].fillna(0))
1    2
3    4
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

If assign to column then not matched values has to be created too - and because pandas no idea what should be is created `NaN`s:

```
df['c'] = df.loc[mask1, 'a']
print (df)
   a  b    c
0  1  5  NaN <- False
1  2  6  2.0
2  3  7  NaN <- False
3  4  8  4.0
```

So if need replace NaN to `0` need [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) - if `True`s is passed values from `a` if `False` is passed `0`:

```
df['c'] = np.where(mask1, df['a'], 0)

print (df)
   a  b  c
0  1  5  0
1  2  6  2
2  3  7  0
3  4  8  4
```

Another pandas alternative is [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['c'] = df['a'].where(mask1, 0)
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  1  5  0
1  2  6  2
2  3  7  0
3  4  8  4
```

All together:

```
some_dict = {'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': [5,6,7,8],}
df = pd.DataFrame(some_dict)
mask1 = pd.Series([False, True, False, True])
df['c'] = np.where(mask1, df['a'], 0)

mask2 = pd.Series([True, False, False, False])
df['c'] += np.where(mask2, df['b'], 0)

print (df)
   a  b  c
0  1  5  5
1  2  6  2
2  3  7  0
3  4  8  4
```

Another idea is use [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) with `fill_value=0`:

```
some_dict = {'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': [5,6,7,8],}
df = pd.DataFrame(some_dict)
mask1 = pd.Series([False, True, False, True])
df['c'] = df.loc[mask1, 'a']
print (df)
   a  b    c
0  1  5  NaN
1  2  6  2.0
2  3  7  NaN
3  4  8  4.0

mask2 = pd.Series([True, False, False, False])
df['c'] = df['c'].add(df.loc[mask2, 'b'], fill_value=0)
    
print (df)
   a  b    c
0  1  5  5.0
1  2  6  2.0
2  3  7  NaN
3  4  8  4.0
```

Comment: THANK YOU! :D `np.where` is magical, is there no equivalent function in pandas?

Comment: @armara - You can use `df['c'] = df['a'].where(mask1, 0)`. Btw, if need  `+ NaN` values need `.add`, added to end of answer.

Comment: @armara of course: [`df.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

Comment: @PierreD - Or here [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) - processing one column

Answer (score 1):

Try to always match the lvalue's index with the rvalue's one. Otherwise, pandas does its best to reindex the two before doing your operation.

Also, always explicitly set a new column to some default value of your choice, e.g. 0, before doing stride assignments (it will also give you the correct `dtype`).

So, concretely:

```
some_dict = {'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': [5,6,7,8],}
df = pd.DataFrame(some_dict)
mask1 = pd.Series([False, True, False, True])
df['c'] = 0
df.loc[mask1, 'c'] = df.loc[mask1, 'a']

mask2 = pd.Series([True, False, False, False])
df.loc[mask2, 'c'] += df.loc[mask2, 'b']

print(df)
   a  b  c
0  1  5  5
1  2  6  2
2  3  7  0
3  4  8  4
```